# .htaccess remove pattern from url

Tags: .htaccess

is there any way to remove some pattern from url?

For exampple this is my pattern `-=-something_dynamic-=-` 
and here is my url

```
_http://mysite.com/category/-=-something_dynamic-=-subcategory/
```

that I wish to become

```
_http://mysite.com/category/subcategory/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(category)/.*?(subcategory)/?$ /$1/$2/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: I think the point is that `something_dynamic` must be _dynamically_ matched, rather than statically in the RewriteRule.